# NSFetchedResultsController with data not updating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm making an app which fetches a list of products from a server. I then store them in a Core Data database and I present them using [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) and the datasource is a NSFetchedResultsController. When I change the product details in the server, I want my iOS app to synchronize and make the necessary changes so I implement the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method. How should I update my gridView properly?

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [_currentData insertObject:anObject atIndex:newIndexPath.row];
                [_currentData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [_gmGridView insertObjectAtIndex:newIndexPath.row animated:YES];
                [_gmGridView removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row animated:YES];

                [_gmGridView reloadObjectAtIndex:newIndexPath.row animated:YES];
                [_gmGridView reloadObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row animated:YES];

                [_gmGridView reloadData];

                //[self updatePageControl];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [_currentData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                [_gmGridView removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row animated:YES];
                //[self updatePageControl];
                [_gmGridView reloadInputViews];
                [_gmGridView reloadData];

                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [_gmGridView reloadObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row animated:YES];

                ////////might be irrelevant, but just trying it out
                [_currentData insertObject:anObject atIndex:newIndexPath.row];
                [_currentData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [_gmGridView insertObjectAtIndex:newIndexPath.row animated:YES];
                [_gmGridView removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row animated:YES];

                [_gmGridView reloadObjectAtIndex:newIndexPath.row animated:YES];
                [_gmGridView reloadObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row animated:YES];

                ////////


                [_gmGridView reloadInputViews];
                [_gmGridView reloadData];

                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [_currentData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [_currentData insertObject:anObject atIndex:newIndexPath.row];
                [_gmGridView removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row animated:YES];
                [_gmGridView insertObjectAtIndex:newIndexPath.row animated:YES];

                [_gmGridView reloadInputViews];

                [_gmGridView reloadData];

                break;
        }
}
```

Some details:

```
_currentData = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]mutableCopy];
//I did this because previously I wasn't using a fetchedResultsController but a NSMutableArray instead. I know that it's inefficient (because I have 2 models) but this is the simplest implementation I want to do now.
```

I make the CoreData changes in a different class by modifying the same UIManagedDocument alloc,init-ed from the same local URL.

However, I get 2 important problems:

- The items in the database are updated (eg. change of product name or price) but the changes are not reflected in the UI, ie I can't reload my GMGridViewCell properly. (take note of the code related to reloading above)
- Most of the time, the products I update in the server are duplicated in the database although I have a mechanism to prevent such an error. (Before I create a product, I first search for an existing one using a unique identifier. If there is an existing product, I just modify its details). Here's the code:

---

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Product"];        

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"product_id = %@", [imonggoInfo   objectForKey:PRODUCT_ID]];    

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];    

request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray 

arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];  NSError *error = nil;  

NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (!matches | ([matches count] > 1)){
    //handle error
}else if ([matches count] == 0){
    //make a new product
}else{
    //return existing
    item = [matches lastObject];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I have to listen to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and I have to merge the changes in the context modified in the background thread and the one in the main thread. I got the idea from the chosen answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192916/nsfetchedresultscontroller-does-not-update-tableview-after-uimanageddocuments-ge)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextChanged:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

//Then the changes in the context has to be merged

```
- (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSLog(@"contextDidSave Notification fired.");
    SEL selector = @selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:);
    [self.itemDatabase.managedObjectContext performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO]; 
}
```

Comment: You're referring to a method "contextChanged" but in the example below it 's called "contextDidSave". Just a minor detail.